# Xamarin - Adding IsEnable Property to Item.Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, picker

I there a way I can set **IsEnable** property to an Item in Picker.Item?

I need to do like the example below, set the IsEnable property to the first Item. Is there any workaround to this?

```
<Picker>
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String IsEnable="true">Option 1</x:String>
        <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
        <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
        <x:String>Option 4</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the selected item you can set the SelectedIndex property on the Picker itself either by binding it or setting it manually.

```
<Picker 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
/>
```

In your case you would set it to 0.

**UPDATE:**
To actually add an IsEnabled to each answer and implement those items as unpickable in the list you would probably need to look into creating a custom bindable property and custom renderers for each platform. This feature is not in Xamarin Forms at the moment so you'll have to create your own. Additionally it would probably be easier to just alter the Items collection to not contain unpickable items. I think this would be more user friendly as well.

Comment: Does not work for me, I want to show all items in the Picker, but to Disable (Grayed out) some items when specific requeriments are met, So I want to be able to Bind IsEnabled={Binding someboolean}

Answer (score 1):

If by IsEnable you mean to set the item as the default one, adding `SelectedIndex="0"` to the Picker declaration should work. Eg. `<Picker SelectedIndex="0">...</Picker>`